# How to Replicate Elementor Licensing Model

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, updates, automatic-updates, licensing

I plan on selling premium WordPress plugins and I'm looking to implement an authentication model similar to Elementor where the end user is required authenticate their domain with my server in order to receive continuous / automatic plugin updates.

What is the technical background on how to implement this licensing model?

Answer (score 1):

There are several different possibilities to implement a licensing / updating system.

You can refer to [this tutorial](https://rudrastyh.com/wordpress/self-hosted-plugin-update.html) to build your own update server (as plugins hosted on wordpress.org can not be prevented to update by licensing).

Building up on this is [this tutorial by the same author](https://rudrastyh.com/wordpress/check-license-key-in-plugin-updates.html) on how to check for a license key in the updating process.

Happy Coding!

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Please see the question again. I am specifically asking how this work via authentication method. This is not the standard licensing approach you are referencing. BTW, are you a WP dev with experience in this area? Thanks.